# How to sort two arrays based on one arrays data

Tags: c#

I have two arrays, one for task names and the other one for their due date. Currently I have sorted the date array, but on the output the dates are different for their task name.
How to solve this problem?

int taskNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

```
    string[] taskArray = new string[taskNumber];
    string[] taskArrayDate = new string[taskNumber];

    Console.WriteLine("----------------------");

    for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write TASK number " + (i + 1) + ":");
        taskArray[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Write the date for the TASK number \"" + (i + 1) + "\" with the \"day/month/year HH:mm tt\" format");
        taskArrayDate[i] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------");

    }

    Console.WriteLine("==============================================");

    DateTime[] dateTimes = new DateTime[taskNumber];
    for (int i = 0;i < dateTimes.Length; i++)
    {
        dateTimes[i] = DateTime.ParseExact(taskArrayDate[i], "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm tt", null);
    }

    Array.Sort(dateTimes);
    for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task number " + (i + 1) + ": " + taskArray[i] + " with time on:\t " + dateTimes[i].ToString("dd-MM-yyyy h:mm tt"));
    }
```

Comment: write your own sorting algoritm that sorts all arrays

Comment: Just use the [`Array.Sort()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-6.0#system-array-sort(system-array-system-array)) which sorts two arrays at once. Something like `Array.Sort(dateTimes, taskArray);`

Answer (score 0):

Write a comparer that uses anothor array.
Use List, not original array.

example from microsoft:

```cs
private static int CompareByLength(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null)
        {
            if (y == null)
            {
                // If x is null and y is null, they're
                // equal.
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // If x is null and y is not null, y
                // is greater.
                return -1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // If x is not null...
            //
            if (y == null)
                // ...and y is null, x is greater.
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // ...and y is not null, compare the
                // lengths of the two strings.
                //
                int retval = x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);

                if (retval != 0)
                {
                    // If the strings are not of equal length,
                    // the longer string is greater.
                    //
                    return retval;
                }
                else
                {
                    // If the strings are of equal length,
                    // sort them with ordinary string comparison.
                    //
                    return x.CompareTo(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

usage:

```cs
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Sort(CompareByLength);
```

You can click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-6.0) to see furthur more.

Comment: The assignment require only the vanilla array, without the lists.